# How to add "CLEAR" button to IonDateTime?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4

The IonicDateTime component allows me to save or cancel the date picked. However, I want to be able to clear the value chosen.

I've looked for solutions and one of them was to use pickerOptions, but this overrides the existing buttons that I still need and I'm not certain how I can create the cancel button anyway or reproduce the existing save/cancel buttons.

Here's my code. FYI I'm using Ionic 4 with React.

```
<IonItem>
     <IonLabel position="stacked">End date</IonLabel>
     <IonDatetime id="enddate" name="enddate"></IonDatetime>
</IonItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for this as well and found the below:

```
<ion-datetime
formControlName="myDateCustom"
[pickerOptions]="customPickerOption"></ion-datetime>
```

and then in the TS:

```
customPickerOption = {
buttons: [{
text: 'Clear',
   handler: () => this.myForm.controls['myDateCustom'].setValue(null)}]
```

Taken from the below link:
https://javascriptio.com/view/1360708/add-button-clear-value-ion-datetime-in-ionic